# How to insert two rows for one primary key SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Learning SQL and created the following table:

```
+-------+-------+---------+-----------------------+---------+----------+
| idnum | lname | fname   | rname                 | private | linkblue |
+-------+-------+---------+-----------------------+---------+----------+
| 40256 | South | William | south.william@uky.edu |       1 | weso123  |
| 68123 | Smith | Terry   | smith.terry@uky.edu   |       1 | tlsm321  |
+-------+-------+---------+-----------------------+---------+----------+
```

And I need to use enter the address info for one of the names into another table with the following entries, created table using following code:

`CREATE TABLE ADDR (idnum INT NOT NULL, adtype varchar(10), CONSTRAINT ad CHECK (adtype IN ('bill', 'permanent', 'local')), streetaddr varchar(60) NOT NULL, city varchar(40) NOT NULL, state char(2) NOT NULL, country char(2) NOT NULL, zip varchar(10), PRIMARY KEY (idnum), FOREIGN KEY (idnum) REFERENCES PERSON (idnum));`

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idnum      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| adtype     | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| streetaddr | varchar(60) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| city       | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| state      | char(2)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| country    | char(2)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| zip        | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

But I need to enter two addresses for that person one is a local address and one is a billing address but I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '40256' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Here is the code I used to try and enter in that data:

```
INSERT INTO ADDR VALUE (40256, "bill", "street1", "city1", "state1", "country1", zip1), (40256, "local", "street2", "city2", "state2", "country2", zip2);
```

Comment: You should have a separate column to store the personid. And assign unique value to idnum column. So personid column will have value 40256 and idnum column will have value 1,2,3... Etc

Comment: Which RDMS are you using mysql is  not equal to sQl server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your idnum is primary key and it must be unique in the addr table.

use

```
CREATE TABLE ADDR (
    idnum INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    person_idnum INT NOT NULL, 
    adtype varchar(10), 
    CONSTRAINT ad CHECK (adtype IN ('bill', 'permanent', 'local')), 
    streetaddr varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    city varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
    state char(2) NOT NULL, 
    country char(2) NOT NULL, 
    zip varchar(10), 
 PRIMARY KEY (idnum), FOREIGN KEY (person_idnum) REFERENCES PERSON (idnum));

INSERT INTO ADDR VALUE 
    (NULL, 40256, "bill", "street1", "city1", "state1", "country1", zip1), 
    (NULL, 40256, "local", "street2", "city2", "state2", "country2", zip2);
```

Comment: Now I get error `ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY`

Comment: I changed my answer. added "AUTO_INCREMENT" to idnum